# Recursively going through list and compare with a value (python)

Tags: python, recursion

The task is to go through a list, compare it with a value and then return the amount of times the value occurred. The comparison works and when I find the matching value I want to save it in a list. Then I want to get the length of that list. The problem is that every time i call on the function again the list resets, how do I avoid that?

```
    def count_occurences(values, value):
        matched_values = []
        if values:
            if values[0] == value:
                matched_values.append(values[0])
                count_occurences(values[1:], value)
            else:
                count_occurences(values[1:], value)
        else:
            return 0
        return len(matched_values)
    count_occurences([1, "one", 2, "two", "two", 3, "three", "three", "three"], "two")
```

In this case the expected output would be: 2.

Comment: Can you also put your expected output?

Comment: well, yes, because you are simply using a local variable that you initialize with an empty list... try instead taking the list as a parameter (and DON'T use a list as a default parameter)

Answer (score 1):

As @juanpa.arrivillaga stated in comments, you are initializing `matched_values` to empty list each call, so you are returning nothing effectively.

The script can be simplified, for example:

```
def count_occurences(values, value):
    if values:
        return (values[0] == value) + count_occurences(values[1:], value)
    return 0

n = count_occurences([1, "one", 2, "two", "two", 3, "three", "three", "three"], "two")
print(n)
```

Prints:

```
2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve your immediate problem by simply moving the `matched_values` assignment outside of the function, as shown below.

```
matched_values = []

def count_occurences(values, value):
    if values:
        if values[0] == value:
            matched_values.append(values[0])
            count_occurences(values[1:], value)
        else:
            count_occurences(values[1:], value)
    else:
        return 0
    return len(matched_values)
count_occurences([1, "one", 2, "two", "two", 3, "three", "three", "three"], "two")
```

However, this code really raises more questions than it answers. Presumably you are doing this as a learning exercise as you can easily do this without a special function or recursion. So bearing that in mind I'd ask you:

- What is the point of `matched_values`? By definition it will just be the same entry repeatedly so it adds no information over just knowing the number of matches
- Recursion is a common pattern in functional programming but your function's primary purpose is to mutate a variable outside the function - this is called a side effect and is generally considered undesireable in functional style

With those in mind, you might consider something like this which does away with the list and involves no mutation and no side effects.

```
def count_occurences(values, value):
    if values:
        if values[0] == value:
            return 1 + count_occurences(values[1:], value)
        else:
            return count_occurences(values[1:], value)
    else:
        return 0
```

(which is essentially identical to the simplification suggested by Andrej Kesely above)

Comment: Yes, going through my introduction to python class at uni and this was a question from an old exam. The matched_values was the only way I could think of to get the number of occurrences which was what the question asked for. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

```
 matched_values = [] 

 def count_occurences(values, value, matched_values):
            if values:
                if values[0] == value:
                    matched_values.append(values[0])
                    count_occurences(values[1:], value, matched_values)
                else:
                    count_occurences(values[1:], value, matched_values)
            else:
                return 0
            return len(matched_values, matched_values)

 count_occurences([1, "one", 2, "two", "two", 3, "three", "three", "three"], "two", matched_values)
```

The list was reset at every call of the recursive function `count_occurences` because you recreated the list at the beginning of the function with this line: `matched_values = []`. This creates a new variable `matched_values` that points to a new location in memory and does not have access to what was found by the previous round.

Initializing this empty list before the function is called ensures that the same location in memory will be accessed every time the function runs. Every recursive call will operate on the same list, and you won't lose information.

Comment: "the method does not have access to variables declared outside of it" is incorrect. It's generally good practice to pass objects into functions that use them but it isn't necessary.